# Prevent some of the members to generate xml documentation

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

Is there any way to prevent some members of adding their xml documentation to the xml file in output?
Particularly I want all internal members not to do that. We are writing a framework, and we want to supply xml documentation and pdb to the customers, but we do not want them to see all the internal structure. Also we are protecting our library and I'm worried that xml documentation for internal members will help to deobfuscate the code.

Completely removing xml documentation from these methods is not an option, as this helps a lot for the internal development.

Comment: Depending on the tool you're using to transform the XML docs into readable documentation, you may be able to exclude `internal` members from the transformation process.

Comment: I'm not using any tool. The xml is provided for the VS to work with our library (for intellisense), and it still contains the description for internals. Although VS won't display that, you can still read them by opening a file

Comment: Then IMHO your best bet is to implement a post-build step that removes part of the content of the XML docs (possibly using an XSL transform).